# Vlookup Cell Color Change If Statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

This is currently my vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(C15,Source!$A$3:$L$6066,3,FALSE)
```

I want to add an if statement to it saying that if the vlookup is true, go into the table array and highlight the cell in which the information was pulled from.

Comment: Which table do you want highlighted, the one you're pulling data from or the vlookup cells? The later can be done via conditional formatting. The former may require VBA.

Comment: @AlexWeber The table I'm pulling from is the one that I want to highlight if the vlookup is true.

Comment: It is not possible to change the attributes of another cell with a formula in a different cell.   You will need to use Conditional formatting on the table cells that does the reverse of what you are trying with the vlookup. Like: Conditional Formatting that applies to `Source!$L$3:$L$6066` using the formula `=A3=OtherSheet!$C$15`.  Or some other formula that gets the desired results.